# Swift Protocols causing Invalid Redeclaration and cluttering function table

Tags: swift, protocols

TLDR: Using many Swift protocols in a large project is great for testing and SOLID coding, but I’m getting function clutter and invalid redeclaration clashes. What’s the best practice to avoid these problems in Swift while making heavy use of protocols?

---

Concretely, I want to use protocols to separate responsibilities from view classes such that they don’t need to know anything about the data models used to “decorate” them. But this is creating a lot of functions for my data model classes that are exposed throughout the app, and that are starting to clash with other protocols.

As an example, let’s say I want to set up my custom tableview cell from a certain data model in my project. Let’s call it `MyDataModel`. I create a decorating protocol like so:

```
protocol MyCellDecorator {
    var headingText: String?
    var descriptionText: String?
}
```

And then my cell is like

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var headingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    func setup(fromDecorator decorator: MyCellDecorator) {
        headingLabel.text = decorator.headingText
        descriptionLabel.text = decorator.descriptionText
    }
}
```

Now all I need to do is provide an extension from my data model class implementing `MyCellDecorator`, providing `headingText` and `descriptionText`, and I can plug my data model object into `setup(fromDecorator:)`.

```
extension MyDataClass: MyCellDecorator {
    var headingText: String {
        return “Some Heading“
    }
    var descriptionText: String {
        return “Some Description“
    }
}
```

This makes the cell easy to test; it clearly separates responsibilities, `MyCell` and the UIViewController driving it now need to know nothing about `MyDataModel`..

BUT now `MyDataModel` has two extra properties, `headingText`, and `descriptionText` - available everywhere. But `MyDataModel` already extends 10 other decorator protocols for specific UI throughout my project, and it so happens that another protocol already defines `headingText`, so I get the compilation error “invalid redeclaration of ‘headingText’”.

With all of this headache, I decide to quit, go ahead and just pass `MyDataModel` into `MyCell`, it all compiles but I lose all the aforementioned advantages.

What are good ways, in such a big project as this, to score those sweet sweet protocol wins, without cluttering up my class’s function tables and having redeclaration clashes between different extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with where Andrey is going, but I believe it's even simpler. You just need decorator types, and the way you've described them, they should be able to be simple structs, with no inherent need for protocols.

```
struct MyCellDecorator {
    let headingText: String
    let descriptionText: String
}
```

(I've made these non-optional, and I strongly recommend that unless you have a UI distinction between "empty string" and "none.")

Extensions work almost exactly as you've done before:

```
extension MyDataClass {
    func makeMyCellDecorator() -> MyCellDecorator {
        return MyCellDecorator(headingText: "Some Heading",
                               description: "Some Description")
    }
}
```

In some cases, you may find that model objects have very consistent ways that they generate a decorator. That's a place where protocols will allow you to extract code such as:

```
protocol MyCellDecoratorConvertible {
    var headingText: String { get }
    var descriptionText: String { get }
}

extension MyCellDecoratorConvertible {
    func makeMyCellDecorator() -> MyCellDecorator {
        return MyCellDecorator(headingText: headingText,
                               description: description)
    }
}
```

This example captures the case where the cell happens to have exactly the right names already. Then you just have to add MyCellDecoratorConvertible and the property comes for free.

The key point to all of this is that rather than have `model.headingText` you'll have `model.makeMyCellDecorator().headingText`, which will address your explosion of properties.

Note this will generate a new Decorator every time you access it, which is why I'm using a `make` ([factory](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage)) naming convention. There are other approaches you might consider, such as an `AnyMyCellDecorator` type eraser (but I'd start simple; these are likely very small types and copying them is not expensive).

You can split the UI into modules and use internal extensions. Those will not appear in other modules, which will prevent `myCellDecorator` from showing up everywhere. If more convenient, you can put the `myCellDecorator` extensions in the same file with MyCell and mark them private.

Since this is a large, existing code-base, I highly recommend allowing any existing code duplication to drive your design. There is no one pattern that is ideal for all systems. It's not even necessary to have every decorator follow the exact same pattern (in some cases it may make more sense to use a protocol; in others a struct; in others you might want both). You can create a pattern "language" without boxing yourself into a world where you're creating extra protocols just because "that's the pattern."

Comment: I agree, in most of the cases you need not a single decorator for a table, but as much as the amount of cells you have. Providing simple data structures which cover the cell's ui is an optimal solution.

Comment: Nice - lots for me to digest here! ;-) I was playing around with a struct based design that I briefly note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56323672/1602875) - the only difference from your answer being I don't need any extension at all on `MyDataClass` nor does any other class need to know how bridge the gap (between `MyDataClass` and `struct MyCellDecorator`..

Answer (score 1):

> But MyDataModel already extends 10 other decorator protocols for specific UI throughout my project, and it so happens that another protocol already defines headingText, so I get the compilation error “invalid redeclaration of ‘headingText’”.

I think this is the main pitfall here, that you use single model to provide data for different parts of the application. If we are talking about the MVC pattern, then the single model should only provide data for corresponding controller. I think in this case there will be much less protocol adoptions in the model.

On other hand you can try to split functionality inside of the model:

For instance, if we have

```
protocol CellDecorator {
    var headingText: String?
    var descriptionText: String?

    init(withSomeData data: ...) {}
}
```

we could create something like this

```
class MyCellDecorator: CellDecorator {
    var headingText: String?
    var descriptionText: String?
}

class MyDataClass {
    lazy var cellDecorator: CellDecorator = {
        return CellDecorator(withSomeData: ...)
    } 
}
```

Comment: The data model in this case represents a row in a database for a fundamental content type. You say "the single model should only provide data for the corresponding controller" - but that doesn't really make sense here. Unless you say we might create a secondary kind of model class, like a SQL view - that takes MyDataModel and rerepresents it solely for this controller's purposes?

Answer (score 0):

One struct-based way I've played with is this:

Instead of extending `MyDataClass`, I create a simple struct (which can be fileprivate to the view controller class, or not) that looks like:

```
struct MyDataClassCellDecorator: MyCellDecorator {
    var headingText: String? {
        return "Some heading with \(data.someText)"
    }

    var descriptionText: String? {
        return data.someOtherText
    }

    let data: MyDataClass
}
```

This way `MyCell` can still use the protocol to decorate itself, `MyDataClass` doesn't need any extension at all, and in whatever access scope I want it I get a struct that does the decorating logic for `MyDataClass` + `MyCellDecorator`.